# How to overlap items in an unordered list using CSS?

Tags: html, css

I have a `UL` that I am using to horizontally display `LI`s

I would like to have every `LI` after the first one overlap the previous `LI` by 20 pixels. I tried applying `left:-20px;` to all `LI`s after the first one but this only appears to apply the desired formatting to one of the `LI`s.

You can see what I currently have here:

http://jsfiddle.net/dp9YD/1/

Any suggestions for getting the Third and Fourth `LI`s from my example moved over?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `margin-left` instead of `left`

```
.notFirst
{
     margin-left:-20px;   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using left for your `notFirst` class, use margin:

```
margin: 0 0 0 -20px;
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't need relative positioning for this effect. [You simply need a negative `margin-left`](http://jsfiddle.net/dp9YD/4/)

Answer (score 0):

left won't do anything as the list items are not positioned relative or absolute. Applying negative margin should do the trick:

```
.notFirst { margin-left:-20px; }
```

Answer (score 0):

Give the `UL` position relative and all the `LI` position absolute and `left:0` and `top:0`
This will overlap all the divs but not do the slider style thing you want.
That being said, I don't think you can do anything meaningful without being able to dynamically change the z-index which means using JS in which case you can add additions margin-left:20 to each li to get the effect you want.

Answer (score 0):

There is a better way to solve this one, and you don't need to add any special class to do it.

In your `UL` style just use `padding-left: 20px;` and this will give you the extra space you need for the first `LI` when you `margin-left: -20px;` in your `LI` style